# How to download note and attachment against case id data loader

Tags: data-loader

We want to download all the note and attachment against case id on case object 
With the help of data loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notes and Attachment records are stored in standard object namely Note and Attachment respectively. You can export Note and Attachment using a data loader. If these objects are not visible at the start then click on checkbox "Show All Salesforce Objects"

To export Note and Attachment of specific record then, you need to use ParentId of these objects. As notes and attachment are stored against the ParentId field.

```
Example : Select Id, IsDeleted, ParentId, Title, IsPrivate, Body, OwnerId, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp FROM Note WHERE ParentId = 'Case Id Of a Record';
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I believe that using the standard Salesforce Data Loader the Attachments get exported as .csv format not retaining their original format and type.